# Is there a way to "link" windows authentication mode with a membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory, impersonation

### **Edit:**

I think I can boil it down to: I want to use windows authentication mode, but be able to get a list of users like you would with `Membership.GetAllUsers()`.

---

I'm trying to develop a solution for use on an intranet, so all the users will be authenticated.  I guess I'm looking for a best of both worlds solution.

Here's the gist (I'll edit later for clarification)

- I want to use Windows authentication mode. But then `Membership.GetUser()` is `null`.
- I need a consistent foreign key in my data to reference the authenticated user.  Also I need to have the users email address for notifications; Windows auth doesn't provide this.
- Any queries to ActiveDirectory will require impersonation of the WindowsIdentity.  IT won't provide a "system" account for this use.

Are there any such examples or solutions which fit my needs?

Comment: I'm thinking I need to write an "ImpersonatingActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" for this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Windows Authentication, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name will give you the user's name.  As for the email address, are you using Exchange?

Comment: But, More importantly I would need to maintain a key for use in the data tables.